# Gather all my Google Analytics Properties data

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to gather all my Google Analytics Properties data.

I would like to know how much daily traffic all my sites are getting accumulated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you tried GA API?

Answer (score 0):

You can as Tomek indicates programmatically collate the data from all the profiles, but you cannot add up all the numbers, example visitors. So be careful, alternative is to run a 2nd profile across all your sites, but that of course will only start collecting once you implement it.

Comment: Why can one not add up the numbers ? It's not possible in the GA interface, but no problem with the API (I do this with apps script and Google Spreadsheets), after all they are just, well, numbers. Have a list of accounts, loop through and do a query for each account, store the result for each query, add numbers up, write total to the spreadsheet.

Comment: For most numbers like pageviews this is not a problem. But if an user visits 2+ sites within one browser session will you count it as 1 or multiple visitors? From site perspective it are seperate visitors but from overall look they are just one.